# git reverting the commit which committed already

Tags: git, github, merge

I have two branches:   1.5.testing and 1.9.testing.

I pulled latest code from 1.5.testing (git pull origin 1.5.testing)

I want to merge to 1.9.testing. so

`git checkout 1.9.testing` (pulled latest from 1.9) and merged 1.5.testing by

`git merge 1.5.testing`

---

I got conflicts  and I resolved in 1.9.testing then committed and pushed.

After two days I found there was code was screwed during merge, so I reverted the particular 3 commits by

`git revert -m <commit id>` and I pushed in same branch (i.e) 1.9.testing.

Then I created a new branch with 2.0.testing with the merge of 1.9.testing.

After that development is going with lot of commits.

Now I want to merge 1.5.testing to 2.0.testing.

This time I have one commit ID which is already there in 2.0.testing because of my previous merged and I pushed.

Now I am completely stuck. I want to merge 1.5.testing to 2.0.testing.

Please help. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying that one commit to 1.5 is already part of 2.0's history?

Thst just means it won't have to be merged.

If your worry is that it was reverted and you want the code in thst commit, just cherry pick it.

Or check out the 1.9 you pulled, and rebase interactively what you want.